# Permitir acesso a uma pagina PHP apenas 1 usuário por vez

Tags: php, mysql

Estou criando um sistema de atendimento de chamados, e para evitar confusão na hora de atender uma solicitação, preciso restringir a página PHP que contem os dados do chamado a 1 acesso por vez para cada usuário da equipe de atendimento, assim quando alguém estiver atendendo um chamado, outro usuário da mesma equipe não consegue acessar a página.

Pergunta: essa restrição poderia ser feita usando SESSION?

Comment: A melhor forma de fazer isso é com javascript, pois só com o php, mysql sessoes ou cookies poderá gerar um problema. imagina que o atendente feche o navegador sem fechar a sessao ou sair de forma errada da pagina... os outros atendentes nao poderao acessar a pagina pois o ultimo atendente nao confirmou sua saida de forma correta daquele local.

Comment: Coloquei a tag javascript para ver se aparece alguem, pois eu nao manjo

Comment: @AndreiCoelho A solução pode até envolver JavaScript, mas está ligada a um estado global da aplicação, e esse estado só pode ficar no servidor. O JavaScript pode até ajudar em termos de usabilidade, mas o cerne do problema é server-side.

Comment: Verdade... você tem rasão @bfavaretto, mas só com php mysql vai gerar problema.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho A sugestão que você tinha dado e apagou (por quê?! era boa!) pode ser implementada só com PHP e um BD.

Comment: Daquele jeito sim @bfavaretto mas achei que não foi isso que o Alan perguntou por isso apaguei.. =)

Comment: @AndreiCoelho poderia mostrar a sugestão que você tinha apagado? Ela pode ser útil.

Comment: Então Alan, a minha sugestão era a seguinte: vai haver uma fila de usuários... O atendente que estiver livre, solicita um usuário para ser atendido

Comment: Ele clica em um botão... "Estou Livre"... ai você vincula aquele usuário com aquele atendente.. sei que não é isso que você está desenvolvendo, mas pode ajudar

Comment: @AndreiCoelho, é uma idéia bastante interessante. E acredita que eu poderia fazer isso usando PHP e Mysql, ou Javascript mesmo?

Comment: Desta forma você só precisaria de php e mysql. Pois a fila só está vinculada aos usuários que estão esperando para serem atendidos.. se quiser posso fazer um exemplo

Comment: Por favor, amigo, me dê um exemplo apenas para que eu possa ter uma noção de como seria, depois eu me viro por aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho legal fazer assim:

O usuário que quer ser atendido faz um cadastro mínimo em um formulário
exemplo: nome e e-mail.

Através do metodo post ele é inserido em uma tabela e redirecionado para a fila de espera.

**adicionando.php**

```
<?php

 $nome = $_POST['nome'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];

 // repare que criei um status que será usado mais tarde, se for 0 significa que está na fila
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO fila(id_fila, nome_usuario, email_usuario, status) VALUES (0, '$nome', '$email', 0");

 // abre uma sessao
 $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

 header("Location: esperando.php");

?>
```

**esperando.php**

```
 <?php

 $emailUsuario = $_SESSION['email'];
 $selecionaUsuariosEspera = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fila WHERE email = '$emailUsuario'");
 $usuariosEmEspera = mysql_fetch_assoc($selecionaUsuariosEspera);


 //verifica se o usuário ainda está na fila

 if($usuariosEmEspera['status'] == 1){
//se o status dele for 1 significa que o atendente solicitou a presença em um outro ambiente, e ai ele vai.....

header("Location: areaDeAtendimento.php");

 } else {

  //se não ele continua a esperar.....

?>
<html>
<head>
// repare abaixo que a página vai ficar fazendo refresh a cada 1 minuto(acho)...
// Para que? Para fazer a analise do banco de dados denovo...
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
</head>
<body>

aguarde...

</body>
</html>

 <?php } ?>
```

**areaDoAtendente.php**

Você terá que criar uma tabela de atendimento assim..

-id

-remetente

-destinatario

-msg

-num_atendimento

Quando o atendente clicar no botão "Próximo da Fila!" ele vai para outra página que vai acontecer isso...

**solicitandoUsuario.php**

```
<?php

 //seleciona o último da fila que o status = 0
 $selecionaUltimoDaFIla = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fila WHERE status = 0 LIMIT 1");

  $ultimoUsuario = mysql_fetch_assoc($selecionaUltimoDaFIla);

  $email =  $ultimoUsuario['email'];

  //altera o status do usuario selecionado
  mysql_query("UPDATE fila SET status = 1 WHERE email = $email");


  //seleciona o ultimo numero de atendimento realizado
   $ultimoNumero = mysql_query("SELECT num_atendimento FROM atendimento ORDER BY num_atendimento DESC LIMIT 1");

   $numero = mysql_fetch_assoc($selecionaUltimoDaFIla);

   $numero = numero + 1;

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO atendimento(id, remetente, destinatario, msg, num_atendimento)VALUES(0, '$atendente', '$email', 'Seja Bem Vindo! Em que possoa ajudar', $numero)");

 $_SESSION['id_atendimento'] = $numero;

 header("Location: areaDeAtendimento.php");

?>
```

na area de **atendimento.php** você seleciona todas as postagens aonde o num_atendimento foi = a SESSION id_atendimento.

Acho que ja fui longe demais.. kkk ... não sei se no final é isso que você precisa mas ok

Abraço!

Comment: No final o javascript será necessário.. você vai precisar atualizar uma parte da area de atendimento... tipo uma div... aonde ficam as postagens.. mas a estrutura acho que é essa.. claro que como não sei a finalidade desse sistema, você terá que molda-lo conforme suas necessidades

Comment: http://rafaelcouto.com.br/atualizar-div-de-segundos-em-segundos-com-php-jquery-ajax/ acho que esta é melhor ainda

Comment: muito obrigado pelo exemplo. Não é exatamente na mesma linha que eu ia desenvolver, mas a base está toda ai para criar o que eu preciso.

Comment: Tranquilo... Não esquece de da aprovar a resposta se te ajudou =) abraço!